# SQL - IF EXISTS - SELECT A - ELSE - SELECT B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I call a SQL in a php script. Sometimes there is no value in "DE" if that is the case I would like to get the value from "EN"

It should be something like this but it is not working this way

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT epf_application_detail.description FROM epf_application_detail INNER JOIN app_uri ON epf_application_detail.application_id=app_uri.application_id WHERE app_uri.uri = '/ps-puzzle-daily-download-for-ipad-iphone-327103760.html' AND epf_application_detail.language_code = 'DE' LIMIT 1))
BEGIN
SELECT epf_application_detail.description FROM epf_application_detail INNER JOIN app_uri ON epf_application_detail.application_id=app_uri.application_id WHERE app_uri.uri = '/ps-puzzle-daily-download-for-ipad-iphone-327103760.html' AND epf_application_detail.language_code = 'DE' LIMIT 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT epf_application_detail.description FROM epf_application_detail INNER JOIN app_uri ON epf_application_detail.application_id=app_uri.application_id WHERE app_uri.uri = '/ps-puzzle-daily-download-for-ipad-iphone-327103760.html' AND epf_application_detail.language_code = 'EN' LIMIT 1
END
```

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT epf_application_detail.description FROM epf_application_detai' at line 1
```

Comment: This is a badly maintainable and somewhat illogical way to query, but if it helps you go ahead. Hoewever, can you explain your problem a little better and show what you have tried? Did you look up MySQL's IF syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's another way,

```
SELECT  d.description 
FROM    epf_application_detail d
        INNER JOIN app_uri a
            ON d.application_id = a.application_id 
WHERE   a.uri = '/ps-puzzle-daily-download-for-ipad-iphone-327103760.html'
ORDER   BY FIELD(d.language_code, 'EN', 'DE') DESC
LIMIT   1
```

if there are other languages, you might add a condition

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE a.uri = '...' AND d.language_code IN  ('EN', 'DE')
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 shouldn't it just be `ORDER BY FIELD(d.language_code, 'DE', 'EN')` DE first and not DESC. As it would be easier to read by others and see we want DE first

Comment: @Waygood it will work if you have this condition , `WHERE d.language_code IN  ('EN', 'DE')`. but if not, the first query gets what the OP wants.

Comment: `Sometimes there is no value in "DE" if that is the case I would like to get the value from "EN"` I am pointing out that its __DE__ first then __EN__. +1 for correct answer, I am not questioning you merely pointing out syntax for readability

Answer (score 1):

Don't use brackets before EXISTS keyword, so it should be --> IF EXISTS (SELECT .....